# ASP.NET Web Forms Application Folder not deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, webforms, directory, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The ASP.NET Web Forms Application that I've designed, contains a folder where the excel sheets that I require for the web reside. I've deployed the Web Application to AWS using the AWS Toolkit in the VS 2017, and could successfully get the application running over the Web. But, when I did something on the web (like Upload) which makes use of that folder, it resulted in exceptions and when I look at them through Log files later, I discovered that the Folders weren't even uploaded in the deploy process. Is there any way I could get the folder deployed as well?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the folder is included in your project before publishing. In Solution explorer, click on the **Show All Files** icon

[image]

And once the folder is displayed in the Solution Explorer, right click the folder and then **Include in Project**

Comment: Thanks. But it's included already. No idea why the issue still exists.